# How to get given paragraph content of pdf file using iText library?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, extract

Is there any way to get number of paragraphs or content of given paragraph in pdf file using iText library ?. I saw some classes like Paragraph, Chunk in some code to create new pdf file but I can not find any way to get these classes in reading file. Every idea is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Is the PDF you're talking about a Tagged PDF? If not, you are making the wrong assumptions about PDF. In a PDF, content is drawn on a page. For instance: an iText PdfPTable is converted into text state operators that draw snippets of text to a canvas, as well as graphics state operators that draw paths and shapes. If the PDF isn't tagged, the lines don't know that they are borders of a table; a word doesn't know to which cell it belongs.

The same goes for paragraphs: a snippet of text doesn't know whether it belongs to a sentence, to a paragraph, to a title line,...

Due to the very nature of PDF, what you're looking for may be impossible (using iText or any other software product), or may require heuristics (artificial intelligence) to examine all text state operators and the semantics of the content to get a result that mimics how humans would interpret text.

It's very easy to achieve if your PDF is tagged correctly. See the [ParseTaggedPdf](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=281) example.